# SVN - merging is not merging

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am kind new to the SVN and I am having a problem.

We have the `branch/Project1`.

We need to add complete redesign to the Project1. So after some time, Project1 will be abandoned. But during the new code implementation, we still need to maintain it.

So, I have created `tag/Project1NEW` from branch Project1.

All of the new development will be done in Project1NEW, and bug fixing will be done in Project1. Of course, those bugs needs to be merged in Project1NEW.

My problem is that **I am not seeing my merges from the Project1 to Project1NEW**.

Using **Tortoise**, this is what I have done:

1. Switched to tag/Project1NEW
2. Selected Merge
3. Selected revision that I want to merge
4. Clicked ok

Tortoise did whatever it needed to do, without error.
I got the merge done message.
But I do not see my new code, mainly bug fixes.
What is strange, if I selected to merge again, the previously merged revision is now greyed (saying already merged).

I know, I most likely did the wrong thing :(, but now is kinda to late.
**How can I fix my problem?**

**Ideally I would like to select the merge, and have it merged to my *tag**.

Comment: You should read the documentation before asking http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/ & https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html Your understanding of tags and merges is wrong.

Comment: You are totally correct. I will read it. But how do I correct the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a tag in this case. You should've created a [feature branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature) and use [basic merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync) to merge both branches. Read how merging works in SVNBook and you should be able to solve the issue.

Comment: Cna I create a new branch based on the tag?